# Is it a good approach to make a 'count' column in a comment system?

Tags: mysql, database, join, database-design, count

In my system, there are entities(posts) and comments.

Let's say there are two tables: 'comments' table and 'entities' table

Comments table has a foreign key that references entities called entity_id

There's a thing I concern, which is, I often need to get counts of comments along with entities, and I am using LEFT JOIN to get comment counts.

```
SELECT entities.*, comment_count FROM entities LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT entity_id,count(id) AS comment_count FROM comments GROUP BY entity_id)  
   AS entity_comment ON entity_comment.entity_id = entities.id
```

But using LEFT JOIN and COUNT everytime feels a bit like a waste of both server resource and amount of code,

So I'm trying to add a 'comment_count' column in entities table so I can get comment count easily without joins, updating them everytime they change.

I wonder if it's a right (or efficient) practice to do this.

Let me know if there's a better solution.

Comment: did you try subquery?not to use join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to explain from database designing viewpoint about having `comment_count` column. Using count columns is related to your project conditions:

1. If the number of records in `Comment` table are so much.
2. If the number of selects in `Entities` table are so much.

It's better to use `comment_count` column.

**But**, I do not recommend to have `comment_count` column in `Entities`. The number of changes in `comment_count` is so much. However, the number of changes in `Entities` are seldom.

In this kind of situations, it's better to move more changeable columns to another table. Let named it: `Entities_Statistics` and have a `Entities_ID` as F.K. You can put all your statistics like in it (like number of comments, number of views and etc).

Therefore, you can get your statistics from this new table without aggregation functions like `count(*)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a messy situation.  The `LEFT` is required since there could be zero comments.  But `LEFT` may not optimize well.  Give this a try instead:

```
SELECT  e.*, 
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  comments
            WHERE  entity_id = e.id 
        ) AS comment_count
    FROM  entities e
```

And be sure to have `INDEX(entity_id)` on `comments`,

Comment: In my case, the processing speed was about the same with using LEFT JOIN, but this way was much easier to apply when coding queries than making JOIN so I'm using this query now.